# web video player Picture-In-Picture (PiP) like

Tags: html5-video, picture-in-picture

I'm looking for a web video player (html, js, php..) that looks like a Picture-in-Picture but working as a standard player.
I would like something which:

- can play as PiP but without becoming dark on mouse-over ("back to the tab)
- can have layer controls (play/stop..)
- can be resized more than 50% of screen (unlike PiP) (*)

I need it to be added in a gis-web-server I made, able to be played over a map, to let user observe both map and video at the same time.

(*) Note: I take advantage to ask here if someone can help me (in absence of a solution) to be able to increase more than 50% the size of PiP in a standard html video player (HTML '<'video'>').

Comment: You could also try using **layers** (called `z-index` in the CSS styles) to have the video on a layer above the map (and you can adjust the video tag's size to your preferred 50%). Example: If the map is layer 0 (default layer) then you place a video above it on layer 1 as `<video style="z-index:1" ..your_other_options_here_like_width_or_height >`.